# I cannot access the elements of an array of structure with ->

Tags: c, struct

I'm having a little problem with a function which receives as a parameter an array of structures, the problem occurs when trying to access array elements with operator ->

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int order;
}record;

void entry(record*reg, size_t num_regs);

int main(void){
    record reg[10];
    entry(reg, sizeof reg / sizeof reg[0]);

    return 0;
}

void entry(record*reg, size_t num_regs){
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < num_regs; i++){
        reg[i]->order = i;
        printf("\n order = %d", reg[i]->order);
    }
}
```

throws this error if you try to compile

```
*error #2140: Type error in argument 1 to 'ingreso'; expected 'registro * *' but found 'registro *'.*
```

because it throws this error and how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is not in this code, how are you calling `entry()`?

Comment: we need to see invocation of `void entry(..)` to be of any help, but the problem resides there, since the compiler is complaining that you are passing a `registro*` instead that a `registro**`, probably you have a `registers[0]` instead that `&registers[0]` or you are passing a `registro[NUM]` instead that a `registro*[NUM]`.

Comment: I edited the question adding the full program

Comment: Again, the problem is not in this code.  Once the accessor syntax is fixed per Voland's answer below, this code compiles and runs as-expected. [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/OkkYEz). Post **real** code that exhibits the **real** problem.

Comment: because it does not compile with the operator ->

Comment: It doesn't compile with `->` because that use of `->` is incorrect. Why do you insist on using it? VolAnd and Fisher have both given you correct versions of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between the `->` and `.` operators when accessing data inside of a `struct`.

- `s.a` is just for when `s` is a `struct` and `a` is a member of `s`
- `sp->a` is really just a shorthand for `(*sp).a` This is used when `sp` is a pointer-to-`struct`, and we want to dereference that pointer and access the `struct`'s data all in one step.

As VolAnd said , you are using `reg[i]->order` but you should really be using `reg[i].order`.

---

If it's still unclear...

With your `entry()` function, you are passing in an array of 10 record `structs` called `reg`. You do this by passing a pointer to the array's base address, so the function accepts a pointer of type `record*`.

The elements of the array are `structs`, **not  `struct` pointers**, so you access them with `reg[i].order`, not `reg[i]->order`.

Answer (score 6):

When you use [ ] for pointer you already have a data, so use . instead of ->

```
reg[i].order = i;
```

and the same for printf argument.

Comment: because it does not compile with the operator ->

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code like this and whole of the array printed exactly true:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_regs; i++){
    reg->order = i;
    printf("\n order = %d", reg->order);
}
```

Comment: remove the Index of reg like this : reg -> order = i; I edited my answer

Comment: I don't think this works correctly. Ultimately we want to access `reg[i].order`, which can also written as `(*(reg+i)).order`, given that `reg` is a pointer to the base of the array. Accessing `reg->order` is really accessing `(*reg).order`, which is only the first `struct` in the array. If you run this code, you'll find you only initialized the contents of the first `struct` properly, while the rest contain garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing address of array and storing / collecting is in pointer.
And as the pointer is pointing to array, if you use -> operator to access the structure element it will treat array as pointer and throws error as "error: invalid type argument of â->â (have ârecordâ)".

So you have to use (.) operator instade of (->) operator.

```
for (i = 0; i < num_regs; i++)
{
    reg[i].order = i;
    printf("\n order = %d", reg[i].order);
}
```